# Combine SQL with PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-order-by

```
$months = array('January', ... , 'December');
$sql='
SELECT *
FROM `residencies`
WHERE `Year` = 2010
ORDER BY array_search($months,`MonthFrom`) `DayFrom`';
```

Doesn't work (i already feared that), it's supposed that the elements are sorted by first the position of MonthFrom in the array $months, and those who have the same position should be sorted by DayFrom. I know there are other way's to treat dates but for this query i am bound to this date structure, any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you share a little more code, please?

Comment: How is that related to PHP? Can you give the database backend at least? MySQL?

Comment: the array_search in $months is PHP and the database is MySQL

Comment: It could depend on any number of things including what you are wrapping the query in (inverted comma wise') and what the values are etc

Comment: @Alex: "Could depend on any number of things" ??? Did you read the code? There is a call to a php function inside the single quotes.

Comment: @Antonio That was edited in AFTER my comment :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$month_arr = array("January","February","March");

$months = implode("', '", $month_arr);

$query="SELECT * FROM residencies WHERE year = 2010 ORDER BY FIELD('MonthFrom', '$months'), `DayFrom`;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql='
SELECT *
FROM `residencies`
WHERE `Year` = 2010
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(`MonthFrom`,"%M") `DayFrom`';
```

But this will sort them according to the alphabetical order of the name of the month ? Do you really need that ?

You can also sort them according to `MonthFrom` and them convert it to text in your php code."

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to use a PHP function within an SQL statement. If you need to sort by MonthFrom, which is the name of the month, try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `residencies`
WHERE `Year` = 2010
ORDER BY FIELD(`MonthFrom`, 'January', ..., 'December'), `DayFrom`;
```

(you can fill in the rest of the months)

Answer (score 1):

I presume from the question that you have a month field in the database which is stored in string format, which would, as other commenters have said, make sorting tricky, hence why you were trying to put the months in order using the array.

Others have come up with valid ways to achieve this given that constraint (I think luckytaxi's answer is probably the best so far), but I would say that if you do have months stored in the database in string format, then you definitely have a poor database design, and if you have the option, you should consider changing it.

MySQL can store full dates using the DATE or DATETIME data types, so if you're storing your days, moths and years separately at the moment as it appears, you should change to storing them together in a single field. You can still query them separately, eg if you just need the month, or in any combination - MySQL has very powerful date handling features (and so does PHP for that matter).

Comment: I know, but the database was designed before and other parts of the site rely on this structure so if i just change the database other people's parts won't work anymore - but on the long term it would definitely have to be considered, but well it's not just my call so now i try to live with it till there is an agreement